# The Method 'MultiTween' isn't defined for the type 'FadeAnimation'

Tags: flutter, package

I am using the [Simple_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations/versions/2.4.2) package on flutter and I am running into the following issue:

I am using the methods that are provided in the official documentation but for some reason It's not "defined", I have tried upgrading flutter and reinstalling the package but it didn't seem to work

Picture for reference:
[image: Example]

And here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';


// Create your Animation Example
enum AniProps { opacity, translateY }

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _tween = MultiTween<AniProps>() // <== ISSUE IS HERE
      ..add(AniProps.opacity, Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0))
      ..add(AniProps.translateY, Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0), const Duration(milliseconds: 500), Curves.easeOut);

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>( // <== ISSUE IS ALSO HERE
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: _tween.duration,
      tween: _tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation.get(AniProps.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, animation.get(AniProps.translateY)),Í
            child: child
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advnace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution in case anyone runs into the same issue

Simply go into your `pubspec.yaml` and change the dependency from the latest version to `4.2.0`

Comment: I don't recommend downgrading the dependency, instead, one should look for a migration of the multitween to sth else

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, Just go to your **pubspec.yaml** file and change the version of the **simple_animations** package like this

**simple_animations : ^5.2.0** to **simple_animations : 4.2.0**

Comment: I am also getting same issue even using simple_animations : 4.2.0. Any idea which version will work?

Answer (score 0):

En this link you can check the changes that were made when transitioning from v4 to v5. And you can adapt it according to your needs.

https://pub.dev/packages/sa4_migration_kit#multitween

Instead of MultiTween, movieTweenValue is now used. In this example, you can see the comparison:

```
    final multiTween = MultiTween<String>()
  ..add('width', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 100.0), const Duration(seconds: 1),
      Curves.easeIn)
  ..add('width', Tween(begin: 100.0, end: 200.0), const Duration(seconds: 2),
      Curves.easeOut)
  ..add('color', ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.blue),
      const Duration(seconds: 3));

final movieTween = MovieTween()
  ..tween('width', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 100.0),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn)
      .thenTween('width', Tween(begin: 100.0, end: 200.0),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.easeOut)
  ..tween('color', ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.blue),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3));

// Animation value now has type `Movie`
MultiTweenValues<String> multiTweenValue = multiTween.transform(0.5);
Movie movieTweenValue = movieTween.transform(0.5);

// Accessing value stays the same
final value1 = multiTweenValue.get<double>('width');
final value2 = movieTweenValue.get<double>('width');
```